# How to get & zoom to an average extent of multiple placemarks?

Tags: google-earth-plugin

I have a collection of point placemarks spread across a small area over the google earth plugin, how can I get an average extent (bounding rectangle) of a subset of these point placemarks and zoom to that extent?

Regards,
Shiva

Answer (score 3):

You should take a look at the [GEarthExtensions library](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/)

In particular the [GEarthExtensionsView](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/wiki/GEarthExtensionsViewReference) namespace and the [computeBounds](http://earth-api-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/extensions/examples/bounds-view.html) method.
They will allow you to set the view to a subset of your placemarks easily.

A simple example of the code to do this would be something like:

```
var folder = gex.dom.addFolder([
  gex.dom.buildPointPlacemark([37, -122]),
  gex.dom.buildPointPlacemark([40, -79]),
  gex.dom.buildPointPlacemark([25, -80])
]);

var bounds = gex.dom.computeBounds(folder);
gex.view.setToBoundsView(bounds, { aspectRatio: 1.0 });
```

**Edit based on comment**

If you read the documentation for the [setToBoundsView method](http://code.google.com/p/earth-api-utility-library/wiki/GEarthExtensionsViewReference#setToBoundsView%28%29) you can see the default range is 1000 metres. So if you are working on a smaller scale just set a smaller range value in metres.

```
gex.view.setToBoundsView(bounds, { aspectRatio: 1, defaultRange: 200 });
```

Comment: Thank you Fraser, I tried out your suggestion but its not working for me as expected. The point placemarks with which I am working are situated very close to each other (within 100-150 meters from each other), so it zooms in on only one point.

Comment: Hello Fraser, I will try it with your suggested modification. But this way of getting the extent adds the point features to the GE plugin. Is there a way to avoid adding the point features and still get the extent of the multiple point features?

Comment: Sure, the features passed to the computeBounds method could be from any source. How are you creating your placemarks would determine the best way. Are they in a Kml file or are you generating them via the api? I only showed using the addFolder and buildPointPlacemark as I did not know how you were generating your collection of point placemarks.

Comment: Hello Fraser, You guessed it right. My point placemarks are added to the GE plugin through a KMZ file using the APIs network link technique. I should have mentioned that earlier itself, I missed that.

Comment: Hi, how can I get the overall extent of a subset of the point placemarks already added to GE plugin using a network link? I have to avoid adding the subset of point placemarks again to the GE plugin DOM.

Comment: Accessing the placemarks via a network links is possible, but can be quite tricky. If there is no specific reason for using networklinks then I would use the fetchKml method from the google.earth namespace to load the data. The resultant placemarks would be easy to access the using the standard api methods GEPlugin.getFeatures(), etc...

Comment: Hi Fraser, I tried creating a linestringplacemark by looping through the susbset of major bridge point placemarks. At the end I am not adding it to the GE plugin, instead using it to just calculate the extent of the comprising point placemarks. This method works, but not as expected, it does not zoom to the exact extent of the subset of placemarks, as mentioned in my first comment. I will try changing the defaultRange & scaleRange values of the gex.view.setToBoundsView() function. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would need to see the actual code to help further...I can't say why it is not working as expected for you - could you link to the kml you are working with?